# iOS and Parse.com backend

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

How would you go about designing and managing data for a messaging application on iOS using Parse?

I've been thinking about it for a while now and I'm at a loss... How to have efficient and fast access to data!? I know my way around in SQL and stuff, but this is not SQL... I need an advice how to tie things together and connect the app user with his/her sent messages as well as received messages from other users using Parse backend. Create class for each user? For each conversation? Or just through everything with sender and receiver ID in one class? Is this going to still be fast when the class would have 200,000 entries? This is my main issue... How to manage this part of the app!!

I am currently working on an app but when I started few month ago, I didn't take this into consideration as I wanted to just start and not create obstacles that I don't know much about to begin with.

Just to clear things up, I started learning iOS same time I started this project... I am a computer engineer with strong C/Assembly background and this iPhone stuff been a little annoying initially but I am getting used to it.

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------------

So I have this code in ViewWillAppear in my messageViewController that will load messages in a conversation.

```
PFQuery *Conversations = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Conversations"];
[Conversations whereKey:@"recipientsIds" containedIn:self.recipients];
[Conversations findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading conversations");
    }else{
        // if no conversations found, create one and set conv. ID
        if (objects.count == 0) {
            PFObject *conversation = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Conversations"];
            [conversation setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientsIds"];
            [conversation setObject:@"" forKey:@"messageIds"];
            [conversation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Failed creating conversatin in bkgd");
                }else{
                    self.conversationId = [conversation objectId];
                }
            }];
        }else{
            PFQuery *messages = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
            messages.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
            //sender id is the phone operator
            //[messages whereKey:@"senderId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
            //receiver id is the other user in the chat
            [messages whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:[objects valueForKey:@"messageIds"]];
            [messages orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
            [messages findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                if (error){
                    NSLog(@"debug %@, %@", error, [error description]);
                }else{
                    // messages found and passed thru the objects paramter.
                    self.messages = objects;
                    //NSLog(@"messages: %@", self.messages);
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                    // scroll the table view
                    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height)];
                    //NSLog(@"number %lu", (unsigned long)[self.messages count]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

This will look if there is a conversation with the recipients ID's. The phone operator ID is added to the recipients ID's before this view loads. The code above successfully inserts a conversation record if it doesn't exit.

For saving the the message after user types a message, I have this code:

```
//[self hideShowKeyboard];
PFObject *webMessage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Messages"];

NSString *timeStamp = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                     dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                     timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
//PFObject *sender = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Sender"];
//[sender setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
//[sender setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
//[sender setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
//[webMessage setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
//[webMessage setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
//[webMessage setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
[webMessage setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
[webMessage setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
//[webMessage setObject:[PFUser currentUser] [@"phone"] forKey:@"senderPhoneNumber"];
[webMessage setObject:timeStamp forKey:@"timeStamp"];
[webMessage setObject:self.inputText.text forKey:@"messageContent"];
//[webMessage setObject:self.senderName forKey:@"receiverName"];
//[webMessage setObject:self.senderId forKey:@"receiverId"];
[webMessage setObject:@"text" forKey:@"messageType"];
//[webMessage setObject:@"jon" forKey:@"receiverName"];
//[webMessage setObject:@"1234" forKey:@"receiverId"];
//[webMessage setObject:@"true" forKey:@"me"];

// store recip. Ids like we do in camera view. then we will nest a query call to update
//the conversation class with message ID where recipIds equal to what we have...
//recipIds will be same coz its in one coversation between two or group of users...
PFObject *conversation = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Conversations"];
[conversation setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientsIds"];
[conversation setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
[conversation setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
//    [sender saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
//        if (error) {
//            // show error
//        }
//        // else save is good.
//    }];
self.inputText.text = @"";
[webMessage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"An error occured while uploading the file. Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }else{
        // success!
        // Create the PFQuery
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Conversations"];

        // Retrieve the conversation by id
        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.conversationId block:^(PFObject *pfObject, NSError *error) {

            // Now let's update it 
            [pfObject setObject:[webMessage objectId] forKey:@"messageIds"];
            [pfObject saveInBackground];
        }];
        [self viewWillAppear:false];
    }
}];
```

Please ignore commented code... I have a bad habit of commenting and trying things as I go but eventually I will clean this code when everything is done.

The problem is, this process created 3 entries in the conversation class...
I think it is because I am trying to update that same record in the conversations class with the message ID and in the database the conversations class has three entries and one of them has a message ID... I attached a picture..
I don't know why I am not comprehending this thing correctly... I'm sure it is simpler than what I am thinking...

Also, how do you go about loading the conversations in the inbox view to show sender names? I started writing a process but it is not complete yet... I need to get the conversation and message stuff correctly first...

Can you please point me in the right direction? I think the insertion of conversation isn't correct... Why the recipientIds contains [] only with nothing in them? I set self.recipients before making the segue... Right now I am dealing with create new message process... The inbox view should contain names of senders and I'm not sure how to go about that yet...

Thank you for your help.

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------
Fixed the conversation class issue... Turned out the recipients ID coming empty...

The issue now is when updating the conversation record to add the new message IDs it only updates the last one... It is string type column instead of array type... What should I do? The update process is in the second code block above.

OMG this thing won't let me post images until I have 10 reputation... Sheesh.

EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------------

So I fixed the other issue but now I have an issue with this piece of code when I try to update the conversation record:

```
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.conversationId block:^(PFObject *pfObject, NSError *error) {
            if(error){
                NSLog(@"Error occured while getting conversation object");
            }else{
                // Now let's update it with some new data. 
                [pfObject setObject:self.messageIds forKey:@"messageIds"];
                [pfObject saveInBackground];
            }

        }];
```

As soon as it enters the first line, it throws this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: __NSArrayI'

self.conversationId is string type!! Not array... Which array is it complaining about!! I don't understand...

In my .h:
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *conversationId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *messageIds;

Any ideas?

EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I'm trying to update the conversation record to add the new message to the messageIds column...

```
[webMessage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"An error occured while uploading the file. Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}else{
    // success!
    // Create the PFQuery
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Conversations"];

    // Retrieve the conversation by id
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.conversationId block:^(PFObject *pfObject, NSError *error) {
            if(error){
                NSLog(@"Error occured while getting conversation object");
            }else{
                // Now let's update it with some new data. 
                [pfObject setObject:self.messageIds forKey:@"messageIds"];
                [pfObject saveInBackground];
            }

        }];
    [self viewWillAppear:false];
}
```

}];

EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I dropped the Conversations class since I thought because the messageIds column is string type and not array. Now I get this error:

Error Domain=Parse Code=120 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 120.)" UserInfo=0x110023400 {error=cache miss, code=120}

I don't know what's wrong with this... 
All I want to do is update the conversation record with the new message object ID.
I saw online many people are doing this but I don't get why I am getting this error...The saving is not taking place... Is there a certain way to update a row in Parse?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve when you get that error? What are you querying for?

Comment: Well, after uploading the new message the user just typed to the database, I want to update the conversation record that contains the messageIds that point to the messages to this conversation (per your original suggestion, right?) So I look for the conversation object because I already have it's objectId from viewWillAppear and then I add the webMesssage objectId to the @"messageIds" in the conversation record and then call save in saveInBackground. But code breaks as soon as this line executes: [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.conversationId block:^(PFObject *pfObject, NSError *error)

Comment: So I'm not sure which array it's error'ing out for... self.conversationId is a string... This is how I tried to implement your solution... I hope I am doing the right thing..?

Comment: I posted one more update... I don't know what I am doing wrong to update a row in Parse.. Is there a certain way to update a row? Why the way I am doing it doesn't work?

Comment: updating the conversation object should not be done on the client, but rather in an afterSave hook in cloud code. read about afterSave here: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is quite old now, this tutorial should get you started:
http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com

I would recommend creating a conversation class that contains an object for each and every conversation. Also, a messsage class for every message. The conversation class contains a column that is an array with pointers to every message in the conversation. This way, it would be super fast to get all the messages in a conversation, with A SINGLE QUERY, using includeKey on the messages column.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try your suggestion in code to get a better handle on this. I will update with the result.

Comment: Great. Feedback on how it goes is nice for later reference

Comment: EDIT!! I checked the recipients and it was coming empty!! Ok so I fixed that now. The problem now is that the update to conversation record with the new message ID is causing it to have only the last message ID... It says string type column... Not array... The update of conversation is in the second code block above... I will attach an image to it... Thank you Handsomeguy.

Comment: I think I know why it had only the last entry because now I need to query for all messages and add them with the one being sent... Lol... I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: So question, now that all messages from all users are under one class which is messages class... Is this going to still be fast? Just because the conversations class contains the messages IDs, it will be fast? That would be nice... Now I need to see how I can find the senders and fill the inbox view... Then I need to figure out the push notifications so user would get an alert when they get a message... Hopefully that won't be so difficult. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I added one more update... The whole logic should be working... Except that last block is giving me errors..

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution. I was able to successfully implement this technique. I have another problem that you might be able to help me with but I will ask it in a different question!

Comment: This is where my other question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622925/sorting-results-from-parse-is-not-working-as-expected-with-query-limit

Comment: Sorry @M5er, I have been away. Glad you worked out your other question

Answer (score 0):

M5er... it is really not a bad thing to try things then comment them out! I do the same thing. It allows me see what doesn't work and keeps from going in circles. Cleaning up later is easy... doing the same thing over and over cause you don't remember what you did... that can cause a little insanity!

Comment: That's so true!! I'm planning to clean up the code before I submit to Apple... Just working on final touches :)